# Insertar estilos Woocommerce según página

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Woocommerce y quería ver si se puede insertar los estilos de woocommerce (ya que mete los estilos "responsive" a la tabla del carrito y demás) justo cuando se acceda al carrito.

En mi fichero `functions.php` tengo `add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );` y hasta ahí perfecto pero... ¿cómo podría hacerlo para que lo haga salvo en el carrito y en el checkout?

He probado algo tipo

```
function controlaEstilos(){

if (!is_cart() || !is_checkout()){
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
}

}
add_action('init','controlaEstilos');
```

Pero seguramente ese `add_action` esté mal y no consigo hacerlo.

**EDITO**:

Mi función ahora trabaja de esta forma:

```
function insertaEstilos(){  
  if(is_cart()){
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_css', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_layout', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_smallscreen', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css');
  }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' ); // Quitamos los estilos woocommerce

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','insertaEstilos',100);
```

Con esto sí consigo que en el carrito sea cuando me cargue sus estilos pero creo que me falta algo ya que, lo que me carga es el carrito en su modo "responsive".

Comment: La función init se activa en los primeros puestos, posiblemente cuando tu función se activa woocoommerce aun no ha cargado los estilos, por ende no los puede borrar, puedes usar el hook wp_enqueue_scripts con una prioridad de 100 o mas

Comment: @JefferzonBollo he probado pero tampoco consigo que me funcione...edito la pregunta principal porque ahora me topo con un problema. La idea es aprovechar cómo trata el carrito Woocommerce que lo vuelve responsive rápidamente pero no consigo apañar cómo lo quiero

Answer (score 1):

Podés simplificar la remoción de estilos usando sólo el filtro, que se aplica sólo si wc está activo, modificando un poco el ejemplo de la documentación.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/#section-2

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );
function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
  if( !is_cart() ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );    // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] );     // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
  }
  return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

Algo mas compacto, menos autodocumentado

```
  return is_cart() ? $enqueue_styles : false;
```

Los id de estilos y scripts los podes ves en el source ( donde se hace el `apply_filter` )
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-frontend-scripts.html#source-code
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/bcdfe3cb68b29c374349474d15fe0431164f4254/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php#L58

Hay soporte básico para varios themes, podés verlos con una búsqueda por nombre del filter https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?q=woocommerce_enqueue_styles

---

Lo del carrito "en modo responsive" debe ser que te toma los estilos desde woocommerce blocks.

Woocommerce blocks

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/

- para deshabilitar los estilos de wc-blocks

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/issues/3032#issuecomment-680009559

https://themesharbor.com/disabling-css-styles-of-woocommerce-blocks/

```php
function disable_woocommerce_block_editor_styles() {
  wp_deregister_style( 'wc-block-editor' );
  wp_deregister_style( 'wc-block-style' );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'disable_woocommerce_block_editor_styles', 1, 1 );
```

- El fix es mencionado/sugerido en este issue

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/issues/509#issuecomment-490888001

- Theming wc-blocks

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/tree/main/docs/theming

- Estilando cart y checkout:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/blob/main/docs/theming/cart-and-checkout.md